# Toggling a div directly under a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have some code that opens a div when the button is pressed using toggle. But I want the div to be displayed directly underneath the button with no white space. However the code only works when you have two line breaks. Why is this and how can I make it work properly?

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:80%;" class="article-toggle" >
<button style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:100%;">Open/Close the box</button>
</div><br /><br />
<div style="display:none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #4CF; width:80%; height:200px;">Box Opened</div>

<script>
$('.article-toggle').click(function() {
$(this).next().next().next().slideToggle('fast');
return false;
});
</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the gap when the button is pressed:

http://jsfiddle.net/fpzj8z04/

If you remove the breaks you can see it stops working.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have to remove `<br /><br />` from html and `.next().next()` from code.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That was the reason :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the <br>s and adjust your selector accordingly:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:80%;" class="article-toggle" >
  <button style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:100%;">Open/Close the box</button>
</div>
<div style="display:none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #4CF; width:80%; height:200px;">Box Opened</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.article-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now! I am still unfamiliar with script languages. You and emmanuel were right :)

Comment: Yeah of course, I had to wait a while before it would let me accept  your answer.